# What is the origin of this meaning of "syntax-directed translation"

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

The phrase "syntax-directed translation" is [defined in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax-directed_translation) as meaning:

> [...] a method of compiler implementation where the source language translation is completely driven by the parser.

This definition is echoed by [Chris Dodd's answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15984920/7558061).
He states that "syntax-directed" means that semantic actions happen during the parsing process, rather than after a parse tree has been constructed.
This does not match the definition in the Dragon Book, which mainly discusses semantic actions being executed after parse tree construction, although it does mention that it might not be necessary to construct the parse tree in its entirety first.

[These lecture notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20110815055736/http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/lecture-notes/Stanford-CS143/13-Syntax-Directed-Translation.pdf) begin with exactly the same phrase, but then say nothing about the possibility of not building the parse tree.

So my question is, what is the original source of *this particular* definition of "syntax-directed translation"? I have read the Dragon Book very carefully and it is not defined in these terms there.

Comment: It was being used in the 1970s, if.not before, and certainly well before the Green Dragon book. Given the way compilers have been built since about 1968, it is rather difficult to see what other techniques might currently exist.

Comment: It wasn't used with this specific meaning until recently though.

Comment: Generalizing a bit, is your question "how has the meaning of the phrase *syntax-directed translation* evolved over time, and who made each of the various changes to the meaning"?

Comment: No thank you, @torek, I'm familiar with how the meaning has evolved over time. I'm interested in the original source for the recent "completely driven by the parser" meaning.

Comment: OK, so it's a subset of the general question: rather than "who made each change to the meaning over time" it's now "who made this particular change to the meaning". (I don't know the answer to that, but I think this clarifies the intent of the question.)